# A* for finding shortest path and avoiding lines as obstacles

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I have to get the (shortest)/(an optimal) distance between two points in 2D. I have to avoid shapes that are lines, that may be connected together. Any suggestion on how to represent the nodes I can travel on? I have thought of making a grid, but this doesn't sound very accurate or elegant. I would consider a node as unwalkable if any point of a line is inside a square (with the node being the center of the square).

[image]

An example would be going from point A to B.

Is the grid the recommended way to solve this? Thanks A LOT in advance!

Comment: A grid is almost the only way to solve this. You have to have reference points around the map that you can or can't travel between. It's the density of the grid that determines your accuracy. Sorry that's not more helpful but it might push you in the right direction.

Comment: The lines define places you _can't_ go.  Is there any other cost besides the distance?  E.g., is the terrain sloped, and it's harder to go uphill?

Comment: @JCooper: Good comment, but the OP did say 2D so I would take that to mean height doesn't factor into cost.

Comment: Why does it have to be A* search if distance is the only thing that matters?

Comment: @JCooper, no, there is no slope, the lines are the only obstacles

Comment: @Razor, I think I missunderstood you. I need the path, not only the distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is essentially Larsmans' answer made a bit more algorithmic:

Nodes of the graph are the obstacle vertices.  Each internal vertex actually represents two nodes: the concave and the convex side.

1. Push the start node onto the priority queue with a Euclidean heuristic distance.
2. Pop the top node from the priority queue.
3. Do a line intersection test from the node to the goal(possibly using ray-tracing data-structure techniques for speedup).  If it fails,
4. Consider a ray from the current node to every other vertex.  If there are no intersections between the current node the vertex under consideration, and the vertex is convex from the perspective of the current node, add the vertex to the priority queue, sorted using the accumulated distance in the current node plus the distance from the current node to the vertex plus the heuristic distance.
5. Return to 2.

You have to do extra pre-processing work if there are things like 'T' junctions in the obstacles and I wouldn't be surprised to discover that it breaks in a number of cases.  You might be able to make things faster by only considering the vertices of the connected component that lies between the current node and the goal.

So in your example, after first attempting **A,B**, you'd push **A,8**, **A,5**, **A,1**, **A,11**, and **A,2**.  The first nodes of consideration would be **A,8**, **A,1**, and **A,5**, but they can't get out and the nodes they can reach are already pushed on the queue with shorter accumulated distance.  **A,2** and **A,11** will be considered and things will go from there.

[image: Modified image.]

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. +1 for the pretty picture.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! I have a doubt though, how do I know if I'm inside or outside the line? For example, you connected A to 11 and then to 10, but you drew the line outside. I have the same doubt for A8, how can I know that I can't get out (this means that I'm inside and not outside the line)? For example, I don't know how I can identify that I can't connect 9 to 4 (inside I can, but outside not). Maybe I understood something wrong. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: @Clash You're right that's a tough part to handle, but not impossible.  The line from 11 to 10 has to be on the outside because you only consider the convex side.  When inside the figure, you shouldn't be considering 9 _or_ 4 because you can't get to the convex side.  You can only visit the convex side of a vertex and if a path to the next node is outside of the obtuse angle formed at that vertex, then it's not a valid path.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: that does sound sane, I'll check you as accepted answer. I will however first try the grid solution to see if it's fast enough. thanks for all your help and nice ideas!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can solve this by an A* search on a graph defined as:

- Vertices: origin, destination and all endpoints of obstacle edges.
- Edges (successor function): any pair of the previous where the corresponding line does not cross any obstacle's edges. A naive implementation would just check for intersection between a potential edge and all obstacle edges. A faster implementation might use some kind of 2-d [ray tracing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29) algorithm.

I.e., it's not necessary to discretize the plane into a grid, but without it, the successor function becomes difficult to define.

Comment: Another way to approach generating the edges of the graph in this case might be generating a constrained Delaunay triangulation of the vertices (the constraints would be the obstacle edges). A good algorithm for this is `O(nlog(n))` and it should result in a graph with a low edge count

Answer (score 2):

A grid, and A* running through it is the way to go. All games i am aware of use A* or an adaptation of it for the global route and complement it with **steering behaviour** for local accuracy. Maybe you were not aware that using steering behaviour will resolve all your concerns about accuracy (search-engine it).

EDIT: i just remember a strategy game that uses flow-field. But it is not main-stream.

BTW: to get a feel for what steering behavior does for your objects take a look at the many youtube-videos about it. Some of them use the term path-finding in a more general sense: including the global algorithm (A*) as well as collision-avoidance, path-smoothing and object-inertia involved in steering-behavior.